Killable socket in python
My goal is to emit an interface to listen on a socket forever ... until someone up the decision chain decides it's enough.
This is my implementation, it does not work. Mixing threads, sockets, object lifetime, default params and a language I do not speak too well is confusing.
I tested individually different aspects of this code and everything was as expected except the line containing the comment BUG where I attempt to force the main thread to block until the server hears the child screaming or a timeout passes but instead recv() simply doesn't see the change in alive.
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import socket
import threading
import time


MAX_MSG_BYTES=1024
TEST_PORT=42668


def recv( s: socket.socket, alive: bool=True ) -> bytes:
    '''
    Accepts packets on a socket until terminated.
    '''
    s.settimeout(1)  # 1 second
    while alive:
        print("'alive' is still", alive)
        try:
            data = s.recv(MAX_MSG_BYTES)
            assert data  # Empty packets were a problem.
            yield data
        except TimeoutError:
            pass  # expected error, any other is propagated up


def test_nonblocking_recv() -> None:
    # Create 3 sockets - sever administrative, server content and client content.
    # Bind the latter and forget about the former.
    server_s = socket.create_server(('', TEST_PORT))
    server_s.listen()
    client_s = socket.create_connection(('localhost', TEST_PORT))
    content_s = next(iter(server_s.accept()))  # Accept 1 connection.

    # client_s.sendall('If this is commented out, the server hangs.'.encode('utf8'))

    alive = True
    def read_one_message():
        data = recv(content_s, alive)
        print(next(iter(data)))  # BUG this causes outside alive to not be seen

    content_th = threading.Thread(target=read_one_message)
    content_th.start()
    time.sleep(3)
    alive = False
    print("But main thread 'alive' is", alive)

    content_th.join()
    assert threading.active_count() == 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_nonblocking_recv()


I think it's because alive isn't a global variable in test_nonblocking_recv. Try adding "global alive" at the top of the function

@axolotlKing0722 I'm scared of globals. What I am attempting to do is pass a reference to "something somewhere that can be evaluated to bool". In C++ that would be a const bool & function parameter. I'm open for criticism on that design decision as well!

Python is not C++.  There are no pointers.  When you pass alive to recv, that doesn't pass the name alive.  It just passes the value True.  To share a changeable value between functions, you need to use globals.

@TimRoberts That's ... an answer. Certainly the one I was not hoping for ... or expecting at the slightest ... but an answer nevertheless, perhaps The answer.

You can pass an object (i.e. a reference) of any mutable class that contains a flag. Even a list would work. But as you are working with threads, the most appropriate solution is threading.Event. Start with dead = Event(), pass it in args to Thread constructor (and change your read_one_message signature to receive it); replace alive = False with dead.set(), and while alive: with while not dead.is_set():.

The approach above does not use globals, but to expound on the previous comments, globals in Python are not actually global, they are only global within the source file they are in. A global in one file is not visible in other files, unless imported. As long as your file is semantically encapsulated and of sufficiently manageable size, the danger is negligible.


I'm scared of globals. What I am attempting to do is pass a reference to "something somewhere that can be evaluated to bool".

Global variables can be problematic - but sometimes they are the correct thing to use.
"bool"s are scalar values in Python - when you pass alive as a parameter to your function, it will have its own reference of it (pointing to the True value), and it will never change no matter what you do on the main thread: when you assign to the local alive there, it puts a new reference, to False in the local name - the name in the other thread remains pointing to True.  (we usually don't use the terms "pointing to" in Python, I am using they because I think that would be familiar to you).
Just change alive to be a global variable there and it will work.
If you want to constrain the variable scope, you could group are your functions in a class, and have alive be an instance attribute. In this way, other instances of the same class could, for example, listen to other ports.
Anyway, it won't help saying you are "scared" of the correct, simplest thing to do there.
In Python, only the functions which write to module level (i.e. global) variables have to declare them - they are read automatically as globals if they are not set in a function:
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import socket
import threading
import time


MAX_MSG_BYTES=1024
TEST_PORT=42668

alive: bool   # declaration not needed, but helps with readability


def recv( s: socket.socket) -> bytes:
    '''
    Accepts packets on a socket until terminated.
    '''
    s.settimeout(1)  # 1 second
    while alive:
        print("'alive' is still", alive)
        try:
            data = s.recv(MAX_MSG_BYTES)
            assert data  # Empty packets were a problem.
            yield data
        except TimeoutError:
            pass  # expected error, any other is propagated up


def test_nonblocking_recv() -> None:
    global alive   # whenever a value is assigned to "alive" here, it goes into the 
                   #top level var.
    # Create 3 sockets - sever administrative, server content and client content.
    # Bind the latter and forget about the former.
    server_s = socket.create_server(('', TEST_PORT))
    server_s.listen()
    client_s = socket.create_connection(('localhost', TEST_PORT))
    content_s = next(iter(server_s.accept()))  # Accept 1 connection.

    # client_s.sendall('If this is commented out, the server hangs.'.encode('utf8'))

    alive = True
    def read_one_message():
        data = recv(content_s)
        print(next(iter(data)))  

    content_th = threading.Thread(target=read_one_message)
    content_th.start()
    time.sleep(3)
    alive = False
    print("But main thread 'alive' is", alive)

    content_th.join()
    assert threading.active_count() == 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_nonblocking_recv()


But yes, you can use a mutable object instead of a scalar or a global variable.
Without declaring a new class,  a trick to do that is to use a container object, like a list, or dict: both your controller function and the worker will have a reference to the same object. You could have a 1-element list, for example, containing  [True], and chaging that element to False would be visible in the worker:
...


def recv( s: socket.socket, alive: list[bool]) -> bytes: # A mutable object must never be used as default value in  a function declaration - so we don~t set it.
    '''
    Accepts packets on a socket until terminated.
    '''
    s.settimeout(1)  # 1 second
    while alive[0]:
        print("'alive' is still", alive)
        ...
        
def test_nonblocking_recv() -> None:
    ...

    alive = [True]   # a new list, with a single element
    def read_one_message():
        data = recv(content_s, alive)  # we pass the list itself as argument
        print(next(iter(data)))  
    
    ...
    alive[0] = False  #we change the first element on the list. doing `alive = [False]` would simply
                      # create a new reference here, while the worker wpuld keep its reference to the initial list.
                      
    print("But main thread 'alive' is", alive)
    ...


And, if you don't want to use a container, you can create a special class which bool evaluation can be controlled - it happens that the truthness value of any object in Python can be determined by the output of a special named methodn __bool__ (if that is not present, Python will check if it is a container with length, and then it is Falsy if len(obj) == 0, Truthy otherwise, otherwise if it is a number with value "0" - otherwise, the special value None is False, and everything else is True)
TL;DR: create a small class with an internal state which can be changed
to modify it is truthyness:
...

class Switch:
    def __init__(self, intial_state=True):
        self.state = initial_state
        
    def turn_off(self):
        self.state = False
        
    def __bool__(self):
        return self.state
        

def recv( s: socket.socket, alive: Switch) -> bytes:
    ...
    s.settimeout(1)  # 1 second
    while alive:
        print("'alive' is still", alive)
        ...
        

def test_nonblocking_recv() -> None:
    ...

    alive = Switch()
    def read_one_message():
        data = recv(content_s, alive) 
        print(next(iter(data)))  
    
    ...
    alive.turn_off()
                      
    print("But main thread 'alive' is", alive)
    ...

Also, you could group test_nonblocking_recv and recv functions in a class, and use self.alive, as I stated earlier - or, simply move recv to be nested inside test_nonblocking_recv  along with the read_one_message function: the two nested functions would see alive as a "nonlocal" variable, and everything would simply work (read_one_message already makes use of alive as a nonlocal variable in your code)

Thanks for listing my options! So I've fallen in good old object/scalar segregation. Alto thanks @Amadan  : I need consider do I need true ITC or the naive variable-sharing approach I've posted will work.

The variable sharing will work.
The Event object otherwise can be semantically better, although I didn't  list it. In Python will work jsust the same as my Switch class - as internal state changes of objects are guarded by the language. (by the GIL up to 3.12 and by specific mechanisms for the free threading Python from 3.13 and beyond)
